# macOS Mojave - locate not working

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, mojave, launchd

I got a MacBook from my work and wanted to use the `locate` command, but I get the message:

```
WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.
```

I ran `sudo launchctl` and waited some time... It's been two days and I still see that same message. If I ran `sudo launchctl` again I get:

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist: service already loaded
```

Searched for the database and:

```
$ ls -l /var/db/locate.database
ls: /var/db/locate.database: No such file or directory
```

The com.apple.locate.plist file is set with the predefined schedule to update on every Saturday at 3:15

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>3</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>15</integer>
    <key>Weekday</key>
    <integer>6</integer>
</dict>
```

So, it shall update once it was executed for the first time. I'm under Mojave (v10.14.2), new MacBook with SSD and Core i7. `locate` should take few minutes to work on new machines, but it's not the case here.

Any ideas on why it isn't working and/or how to make it work?

Comment: As I see in the plist, you can run `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` in order to build the db earlier. BTW You can use `mdfind`  command to search for files quicker (It uses Spotlight database).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using the MacBook for about three weeks and just put it to sleep everyday. For some unknown reason `locate` was not working. To solve the issue, it helped the classical **"have you tried to turn it on and off?"** After restart, it worked.

As already mentioned, `locate` is configured to update its database every Saturday, so it doesn't find any new file created before it updates. A workaround is to set the .plist file for everyday updates.

And as @mateusz-szlosek suggested, the command `mdfind` is more efficient and can find recently created files using the option `-name`.

Answer (score 4):

Amigo, I might start with launchctl:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
```

Then check for any impediments to obtaining exclusive lock privilege on the nonexistent database:

```
sudo fuser -fu /private/var/db/locate.database
sudo lsof /private/var/db/locate.database
```

Then kill any process reported by either command.  Next, run the db generator by hand, preceded by an opensnoop for debugging if something goes wrong.  You will need to open a new terminal window ( command key - N shortcut, I believe ) and run opensnoop there, exiting it with a Control Key - c combo.

```
sudo opensnoop -cegx -f /private/var/db/locate.database
```

Then over to your original window type:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

Remember to quit opensnoop with a cntrl-c in its window.

F.